# How to catch Vue3 + Mitt event on another router view?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, eventemitter

I have simple [Vue3 application](https://github.com/camohub/vue3-hello-world) which contains router and Mitt event emitter. If I emit an event on router view Search.vue everything works fine. SearchForm.vue components emits onSearch event on Mitt and SearchList.vue component which listen on('onSearch') renders the items list.
But SearchList.vue component works only if SearchForm.vue and SearchList.vue are on the same router view Search.vue. When I import the SearchList.vue to another view e.g. Search2.vue it does not work.

I would appreciate if somebody could explain me what is the problem with events between views.

Comment: Event emitter works in a very simple way, the obvious reason for an event to not propagate to event listener is that an event was emitted before a listener was added. Event emitter is stateless and doesn't accumulate previously emitted events. It likely doesn't fit your case. Use Vuex for this.

Comment: Hmm if I open another view I lost the data on previous view. Why is that happened? Router views are separated from each other?

Comment: They are different instances of different components.

Comment: But if they are components they should share events with emitter. Why not?

Comment: Because component instance that you want to receive an event doesn't exist at the time when you emit an event. See the explanation above.

Answer (score 1):

The router deletes the instance of the component when you move away from it and remounts it when you move back. Basically, unless they're on the same router view, your components don't even exist when the event is emitted.